# Seaborn plots kdeplot but not distplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, analytics, seaborn

I want to plot data from a pandas dataframe column formed from couchdb. This is what code and output from the data:

```
print df4.Patient_Age

Doc_ID
000103f8-7f48-4afd-b532-8e6c1028d965    99
00021ec5-9945-47f7-bfda-59cf8918f10b    92
0002510f-fb89-11e3-a6eb-742f68319ca7    32
00025550-9a97-44a4-84d9-1f6f7741f973    73
0002d1b8-b576-4db7-af55-b3f26f7ca63d    49
0002d40f-2b45-11e3-8f66-742f68319ca7    42
000307eb-18a6-47cd-bb03-33e484fad029    18
00033d3d-1345-4739-9522-b41b8db3ee23    42
00036d2e-0a51-4cfb-93d1-3e137a026f19    42
0003b054-5f3b-4553-8104-f71d7a940d84    10
Name: Patient_Age, dtype: object
```

If I execute this code:

```
sns.kdeplot(df4.Patient_Age)
```

the plot is generated as expected. However, when I run this:

```
sns.distplot(df4.Patient_Age)
```

I get the following error with distplot:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'unicode' and 'long'
```

To correct the error, I use:

```
df4.Patient_Age = [int(i) for i in df4.Patient_Age]
all(isinstance(item,int) for item in df4.Patient_Age)
```

The output is:

```
False
```

What I would like to understand are:

1. Why was the kdeplot being generated earlier but not the histplot?
2. When I changed the datatype to `int`, why do I still get a `False`? And if the data is not `int` (as indicated by `False`), why does the `histplot` work after the transformation?

Comment: Please give us a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your values are not numeric. If you force them to integers or floats, it will work.

```
from io import StringIO

import pandas
import seaborn
seaborn.set(style='ticks')

data = StringIO("""\
Doc_ID                                  Age 
000103f8-7f48-4afd-b532-8e6c1028d965    99
00021ec5-9945-47f7-bfda-59cf8918f10b    92
0002510f-fb89-11e3-a6eb-742f68319ca7    32
00025550-9a97-44a4-84d9-1f6f7741f973    73
0002d1b8-b576-4db7-af55-b3f26f7ca63d    49
0002d40f-2b45-11e3-8f66-742f68319ca7    42
000307eb-18a6-47cd-bb03-33e484fad029    18
00033d3d-1345-4739-9522-b41b8db3ee23    42
00036d2e-0a51-4cfb-93d1-3e137a026f19    42
0003b054-5f3b-4553-8104-f71d7a940d84    10
""")

df = pandas.read_table(data, sep='\s+')
df['Age'] = df['Age'].astype(float)

df.info()
# prints

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 10 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 2 columns):
Doc_ID    10 non-null object
Age       10 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 240.0+ bytes
```

So then:

`seaborn.distplot(df['Age'])`

Give me:

[image]